# SQLite mixing up rows when using the MIN function (also not always returning the minimum)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table which I'm trying to select the minimum values grouped by 2 columns i.e. column 1 and column 6.

Some of the data from the table is the below (just reduced irrelevant parts data down, and omitted additional rows)

```
     C.1 (sID)   C.2    C.3 (Standard_Time)  C.4    C.5     C.6 (SIP)   C.7     C.8 (Unix_Time)
1.   (u'8888', u'G', u'2014-08-10 00:23:57', u'At', u'2', u'10.168.77.10', u'X', 1407626637.0)
2.   (u'8888', u'G', u'2014-08-10 00:23:58', u'At', u'2', u'10.168.77.10', u'y', 1407626638.0)
3.   (u'8888', u'G', u'2014-08-10 00:23:58', u'At', u'2', u'222.222.222.222', u'z', 1407626638.0)
4.   (u'8888', u'G', u'2014-12-11 19:19:19', u'At', u'2', u'10.168.77.10', u'A', 1418325559.0)
5.   (u'1411', u'SM', u'2014-08-10 00:23:56', u'At', u'2', u'192.168.77.114', u'z', 1407626636.0)
```

I was hoping to retrieve rows 1, 3, and 5 (as a result of being grouped by column 1 initially, then by column 6; whereby in column 6 there a 3 unique IP addresses.  My code is shown below (although I don't really want to return Unix_Time twice, but it also aids here in showing what's going wrong).

```
    minList = []
    c.execute('SELECT MAX(Unix_Time), * FROM myTable group by SID, SIP')
    ans = c.fetchall()
    for r in ans: 
        minList.append(r)
```

This code returns -

Rows 3 and 5 as expected, and bizarrely returns row 4 with two different Unix_Times.  The first one belongs to row 1 (which is indeed the lowest value so row 1 should really be returned) and the last one belongs to itself i.e. row 4 (the rest of the row is row 4's)

```
(Both 1 & 4?)   (1407626637.0, u'8888', u'G', u'2014-12-11 19:19:19', u'At', u'2', u'10.168.77.10', u'A', 1418325559.0)
```

N.B. If I run the select statement stating explicitly every column I wish to return (i.e. all of them, so there is no duplication of Unix_Time...then row 4 still returns but with row 1's Unix_Time in place of where it's own time should be.  I.e. it returns:

```
(Both 1 & 4?) (u'8888', u'G', u'2014-12-11 19:19:19', u'At', u'2', u'10.168.77.10', u'A', 1407626637.0)
```

Lastly, if I run a similar statement requesting 'MAX' it appears to run fine.

Any help or words of wisdom is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `sqlite3.sqlite_version`?

Comment: SQLite 2.6.0.  I see from your answer in the other question that I would need 3.7.11 (or newer) for this to work.

Comment: I moved to Python 32bit and upgraded to SQLite 3.8.6.  There doesn’t seem to be an official 64 bit SQLite DLL, which makes me wonder who developed the one bundled with Python 64 (as that good enough as official to me. Nevertheless I’m moving forward once again...and without a headache! Thanks for the advice (here/other answer) on the version number.